# U-boot Standalone Application at Startup

Tags: embedded-linux, boot, bootloader, u-boot

Is it possible to include standalone applications/startup scripts in the u-boot bootup process, and what is the available hooks?

So far I can see from the hello_world example how to compile a standalone application in C, but it still needs to be loaded manually through tftp which I don't want to do.

EDIT: I have found several "hooks" listed in common.h such as

```
last_stage_init()
board_late_init()
```

Where can I find an idea of the proper workflow to add an application to make adjustments to the environment variables?

Comment: It's not clear what your question is about. You want get rid of manually uploading the app via tftp, or you want to store the app in the flash to avoid the use of tftp, or use start up script, or what?

Comment: I wanted to know more on where to add startup scripts before boot - and perhaps my question was framed wrong. I found the hooks listed in board.c - for example the `misc_init_r()` hook and proceeded using that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wanted to use a u-boot startup script but did not know how to proceed and wrongfully used the term application.

I now use the hooks specified in board_r.c, for example `misc_init_r()` and `last_stage_init()` where I put my startup scripts required before boot.

Just remember to enable these functions with `#define CONFIG_LAST_STAGE_INIT` and `#define CONFIG_MISC_INIT_R()`

Answer (score 1):

The basic answer here is that you can have whatever you want run in the CONFIG_BOOTCOMMAND variable and that in turn can load and 'go' your application from wherever you have stored it on the device.